# Из MemoryStream читается мусор

Tags: c#, память, потоки-данных

```
Исходные данные:  0xaa, 0xff, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80

При чтении:       0x3F, 0x3F, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x3F
```

Предположительно большие значения дают это.

```
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(9))
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 0xaa, 0xff, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 }));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я в c# ничего не понимаю, но подозреваю что кодировка ASCII не понимает символы с кодами больше 127 и превращает их в вопросительные знаки (`?` код ascii `0x3f`)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ был прост, System.Encoding.ASCII.GetString портит байты, корректный код выглядит так

```
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(9))
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                // writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0xaa, 0xff, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 }));
                byte[] writeBuf = new byte[] { 0xaa, 0xff, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
                stream.Write(writeBuf);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer));
            }
        }
    }
}
```